# Construct POST data and send it to an external page

Tags: 6, forms

Is there any way to construct post data and send it to an external URL, like how a form will send POST data to action URL?

I am aware of `drupal_goto()` function, but it is not possible to send POST data using it. I am also aware of `drupal_http_request()`, but I do not want a response from the URL here. I just want to submit data to the URL from my custom module. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just use `drupal_http_request` and ignore the response if you don't need it? Also, shouldn't you be checking that your connection has been made successfully? What if there was an error?

Comment: If I use `drupal_http_request()`, the request will be processed and I will get a response within the same function. But I want the user be redirected to the external page to which I am sending POST data. So how do I pass the data and also redirect the user to the same page?

Comment: You can't do that with PHP, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045097/php-redirect-and-send-data-via-post

Comment: thanks for the reference. So can I construct a new form with required values and trigger its action programatically to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah that's the way I'd do it, forward the user on to a page which builds up the form (with the correct `action` attribute) with the fields already in it (probably using `hidden` inputs) and use javascript to submit the form as soon as the document is ready :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PHP question, really. But here's an answer: http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/

Many many caveats; read the comments.

Comment: Just found this, too: http://requests.ryanmccue.info/

Answer (score 0):

[CURL](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is th swiss army knife to do such things. CURL stands for client URL library. It allows you to do everything programmatically what you can do manually in a browser (and a lot more).